# Hover issue in navbar with Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a `navbar` with Bootstrap 4. When I click on a drop-down menu link, it opens and remains open — when I hover on another drop-down link, they overlap.

I want it such that a dropdown link will be closed if I hover on another dropdown link.

Here is the code of my `navbar` drop-down:

```css
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>
         Welcome - Maqbool Solutions
      </title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favion_Y13_5.ico" type="image/x-icon">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="../../js/function.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="font/css/font-awesome.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <!--main container-->
         <!-- navbar-->
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom fixed-top" id="navbar" style=" height: 80px;">
            <div id="logo">
               <a href="index.html">
                  <h3 class="logo_text">Maqbool Solutions</h3>
               </a>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
               <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="ul">
                  <li class="nav-item " align="center">
                     <i class="fa fa-home " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown" align="center">
                     <i class="fa fa-cubes" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                     Products
                     </a>
                     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="products/ims/ims.html">Institute Managment Systems</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="products/pnms/pnms.html">Pension Managment Systems</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="products/pms/pms.html">Property Managment Systems</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="products/labms/labms.html">Laboratory Managment Systems</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="products/apps/apps.html">Apps</a>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown" align="center">
                     <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                     Services
                     </a>
                     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/skill_service.html">Training and Skills</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/indestrial_services.html">Industry Expertise</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/web_service.html">Web services</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/software_service.html">Software services</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/animation_service.html">Animation services</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/graphic_service.html">Graphic services</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/game_service.html">Game services</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/apps_service.html">App services</a>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown" align="center">
                     <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                     Training
                     </a>
                     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/soft.html">Software Designing & Development</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/design.html">Designing & Composing</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/web.html">Web Designing & Development</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/animation.html">2D&3D Animation & Development </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/game.html">Game Development </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/app.html">App Development </a>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown" align="center">
                     <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                     About Us
                     </a>
                     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="aboutus/hwr.html">Who we are</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="aboutus/our_vision.html">Our vision</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="aboutus/our_team.html">Our Team</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="aboutus/policy.html">Privacy & Policy</a>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown" align="center">
                     <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                     Career
                     </a>
                     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="career/jobs.html">Jobs</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="career/inter.html">Internship</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="career/hiring.html">Our Hirring process</a>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" align="center">
                     <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     <a class="nav-link" href="contect_us.html">Contact Us</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <hr class="col-md-12 nav_hr">
         </nav>
         <!--end of navbar-->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add below **`jQuery`** code in your custom **`js`** file

```
$('.nav-link').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.nav-item.dropdown').siblings('.nav-item.dropdown').removeClass('show').find('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
})
```

The issue is when you click on the **`dropdown link`**, a class named **`show`** is added to **`.nav-item.dropdown`** and **`.dropdown-menu`**, So you have to remove **`show`** class when you hover on others **`dropdown link`**

```js
$('.nav-link').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.nav-item.dropdown').siblings('.nav-item.dropdown').removeClass('show').find('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
})
```

```css
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>
    Welcome - Maqbool Solutions
  </title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favion_Y13_5.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!--main container-->
    <!-- navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom fixed-top" id="navbar" style=" height: 80px;">
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <h3 class="logo_text">Maqbool Solutions</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="ul">
          <li class="nav-item " align="center">
            <i class="fa fa-home " aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" align="center">
            <i class="fa fa-cubes" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Products
                        </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="products/ims/ims.html">Institute Managment Systems</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="products/pnms/pnms.html">Pension Managment Systems</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="products/pms/pms.html">Property Managment Systems</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="products/labms/labms.html">Laboratory Managment Systems</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="products/apps/apps.html">Apps</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" align="center">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Services
                                </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/skill_service.html">Training and Skills</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/indestrial_services.html">Industry Expertise</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/web_service.html">Web services</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/software_service.html">Software services</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/animation_service.html">Animation services</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/graphic_service.html">Graphic services</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/game_service.html">Game services</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/apps_service.html">App services</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" align="center">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Training
                                </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/soft.html">Software Designing & Development</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/design.html">Designing & Composing</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/web.html">Web Designing & Development</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/animation.html">2D&3D Animation & Development </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/game.html">Game Development </a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="training/app.html">App Development </a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" align="center">
            <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    About Us
                                    </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="aboutus/hwr.html">Who we are</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="aboutus/our_vision.html">Our vision</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="aboutus/our_team.html">Our Team</a>

              <a class="dropdown-item" href="aboutus/policy.html">Privacy & Policy</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" align="center">
            <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Career
                                    </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="career/jobs.html">Jobs</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="career/inter.html">Internship</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="career/hiring.html">Our Hirring process</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item" align="center">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <a class="nav-link" href="contect_us.html">Contact Us</a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
      <hr class="col-md-12 nav_hr">

    </nav>
    <!--end of navbar-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: active class are not gone . i have try your suggestions but not work can you help me

Comment: @MuhammadIlyas Maybe you have not put the **`jQuery`** code in right place because it's working in above snippet. You have to put the **`jQuery`** code below bootstrap.js

Comment: sir i try  jQuery code in script tag but not fixed. and change the order of bootstrap.js file also

Comment: @MuhammadIlyas could you show me any screenshot of your script order

Comment: @MuhammadIlyas Where you have put the script code? I cant find it in the code of the link you provided

Answer (score 0):

In your code, while mouse over or click event is fired , "show" class is applied to child menu (dropdown-menu) element.

So you can override that class like:

```
.dropdown-menu.show {
   display: none;
}
```

to solve your issue and to display menu items only on hover

Comment: No I think this is has little problem. Click on link item more than one and then hover on them then you will get the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add following CSS lines:

```
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu,
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu.show {
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown > .dropdown-menu,
    .dropdown > .dropdown-menu.show {
        display: none;
    }
```